# Get font of selected text in JEditorPane

Tags: java, fonts, combobox, jeditorpane, selectedtext

Basically the question says it all;

I have a JEditiorPane with the content type 'text/html'. I have created a font family and font size combo box and enabled them using the StyledEditorKit actions. This works great and I can change the font attributes of selected text (you what it does...)

The only thing is when I select the text it's a bit confusing because the ComboBox's still show the users previous selection. I would love to implement the functionality to update the combo box values according the selected text but cannot figure out how to get the selected texts font! I've tried all sorts of crafty workarounds - non of which have worked

Any Help appriciated

Thanks In Advance

Andy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a `CaretListener`. On each caretUpdate use the code

```
AttributeSet attrs=((StyleEditorKit)editorPane.getEditorKit()).getInputAttributes()
StyleConstants.getFontFamily(attrs);
```

Comment: sorry for my slow reply and thank you for your answer. It works perfectly, I had to change it to a `MutableAttributeSet` but it was no biggy and once I did it does exactly what I want. Thanks, 5 stars!!!!!